# FATA[0005] unable to pass CNI pod CIDR range check : cni pod cidr 192.168.0.0/16 overlaps with ip 192.168.0.2 of node

Tags: docker

The error in title is stopping the installation of Docker-UCP on Ubuntu 18.04 AMD64:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably your host network has conflict with default pod cdr network. You can ommit this issue with specifying another pod-cdr range.

e.g.:

```
--pod-cidr 10.0.0.0/16
```